# How to redirect a Single Page Application in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

I have a signup endpoint for a Spring Boot app. The UI is a React Single Page App.

I want to make the SPA app redirect to "/login" (making a GET request).

How should I do this?

I tried the following two approaches:

The first approach doesn't work as the response http code in postman is 200 and the body only includes "redirect:/login"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(@RequestBody CustomUserDetails user, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String userName = user.getUsername();
    logger.debug("User signup attempt with username: " + userName);

    try{
        if(customUserDetailsService.exists(userName))
        {
            logger.debug("Duplicate username " + userName);
            return "redirect:/login";
        } else {
            customUserDetailsService.save(user);
            authenticateUserAndSetSession(user, response);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
            return "redirect:/login";
}
```

I also tried the following approach. But it throws `Method Not Allowed` exception. Because I have a controller for `login` when the request is of type `POST`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView signup(@RequestBody CustomUserDetails user, ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String userName = user.getUsername();
    logger.debug("User signup attempt with username: " + userName);

    try{
        if(customUserDetailsService.exists(userName))
        {
            logger.debug("Duplicate username " + userName);
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login", model);
        } else {
            customUserDetailsService.save(user);
            authenticateUserAndSetSession(user, response);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
}
```

How am I supposed to handle this redirect ? What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is you shouldn't redirect in the Spring Boot Controllers at all.

What you need to do is return status codes from `/signup` endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody CustomUserDetails user, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String userName = user.getUsername();
    logger.debug("User signup attempt with username: " + userName);

    try{
        if(customUserDetailsService.exists(userName))
        {
            logger.debug("Duplicate username " + userName);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            customUserDetailsService.save(user);
            authenticateUserAndSetSession(user, response);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

So the endpoint will return HTTP status 200 when there is a User with the username in the system and HTTP status 404 when there is no User found with the given username. You have to use this information to make the Routing in the Front End Single Page Application (This is how it is done in AngularJS, etc.)

Comment: what if I want to also send a custom error code which implies there was an existing username ?

Comment: You can send any status code as long as you handle it in the front end.

Comment: What about logout? how should I handle it in a SPA? should I just stop putting the JWT (authentication token) in the header and that's it ?

Comment: Yes. SPA are supposed to consume a REST API and REST are said to be stateless. Which means you never a Login Session. Just clear the JWT Token from the Client end.

Comment: Don't we need to delete the JSESSION cookie and invalidate it on the server side ?